# How to handle arraylist in javascript function.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing arraylist object to javascript function on the click on button.below is my code. But I am unable to iterate that list in javascript.

```
<input type="button" onclick="viewSelectedOU('${quickLink.orgList}')"  class="btn" value="view"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function viewSelectedOU(selectedOU){

    for(var i=0; i<selectedOU.length; i++){
        var orgList1 = selectedOU[i];

    }
}
</script>
```

can anyone tell me how to iterate java.util.ArrayList into javascript.?

Comment: Do `console.log( typeof selectedOU );` inside the function and see what it says ?

Comment: **How** do you pass the arrayList ? What's in `'${quickLink.orgList}'` ? A relevant tag is probably missing here, to precise the templating system you use.

Comment: *"But I am unable to iterate that list in javascript."* what happens instead? To me it looks like you are always passing a string to the function.

Comment: @adene0 'console.log( typeof selectedOU );' prints 'string'.

Comment: @dystroy ${quickLink.orgList} is java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: View rendered page sources(Ctrl+U), what you see there? Try serialize your java array to JSON first

Comment: @Yaroslav Bigus  viewSelectedOU('[com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.model.QuickLinkOrgList@ece671, com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.model.QuickLinkOrgList@3ad126,   com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.model.QuickLinkOrgList@d823db, com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.model.QuickLinkOrgList@8f11e2]')

Comment: 1. Your are passing string (see quotes)

Comment: 2. serialize you object to json your collection. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

check your rendered page, it shoud be something like onclick="viewSelectedOU([1,2,3,4])"
here is example of 2 calls:

http://jsfiddle.net/ybigus/K6CUm/

```
<a href="#" onclick="testArray([1,2,3])">Test simple array</a>
<a href="#" onclick="testArray2([{name:'yaro'},{name:'john'}])">Test object array</a>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
for(var i=0;i<selectedOU.all.length; i++){
        var value = selectedOU.all(i);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `selectedOU` has a property `all` and is a function?